# C++ uint8_t array length

Tags: c++, arrays

I trying to get the size of array, but I gets funny results:

sizeof(new uint8_t[1]) gives me 4 while sizeof(uint8_t) gives me 1.

How do i get the size of an uint8_t array?

Comment: `new` returns a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new uint8_t[1]` is a pointer, not an array.

> How do i get the size of an uint8_t array?

For an array of `N` elements, the size in bytes is

```
sizeof(uint8_t[N]);
```

or

```
N * sizeof(uint8_t);
```

However, if `uint8_t` exists, it will be one byte; so in this case the array size is just `N`.